# Why is my player stats agility higher than my upgraded agility level?

Tags: dark-souls-2

My agility when I talk to the Emerald Herald to look at my upgrades is 105. When I check my player stats my agility (AGL) is 109.

At first I figured some piece of my equipment gave me boost but I have taken everything off and still have the 109 AGL.

I can't complain about the extra points on a DEX character but I would like to know where the extra 4 points came from?

Comment: could it be that a piece of gear has an agility penalty of -4?

Comment: My ADP and ATN make up 105 AGL so that should be what my agility is at which is shows when upgrading with Emerald. but 109 outside of the upgrade page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some piece of equipment you have equipped is increasing your Agility. The upgrade screen doesn't account for equipment modifiers, which causes the inconsistency. Most likely, your Adaptability is being increased by 5 by something like the [Simpleton's Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Simpleton's+Ring), which would result in the +4 Agility difference.